# How to deactivate and activate a USB bar code scanner,?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Motorola DS9208 scanner that I use in excel to scan items into my workbook that updates my inventory. I need it to scan and input the code into a certain text box, txtBarCode, but when I go elsewhere in the program the scanner will scan whatever gets in its path and enter it into whatever I am doing. Is there a way to only run the scanner when a certain userform is open? Thanks for any help!

Comment: DS9208 seems to be programmed by flashing specific barcodes, so I don't see how you can choose to activate or deactivate it. Maybe you can use it in trigger mode instead of auto mode?

Comment: How do you do that if it's not to much trouble? That might work!!

Comment: § 4-13 on the [manual](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra_new_ia/en-us/manuals/barcode-scanners/ds9208-prg-en.pdf)

Comment: your scanner is set to presentation mode (always on)  ... scan the tags on page 4-6 (parameter #145)  just to get a feel for programming the scanner  ... then on page 4-13 as per @VincentG, scan one of the two tags that require a trigger button to be pressed. one of them turns on a targeting light.

Comment: you may have to scan Parameter # 236 on page 4-5 before doing any of the other steps, but try the other steps first